# How to create an Orbit Chart in R? (Plotly/ggplot2)

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, plotly

I have spent time researching with no direction on how to create an [orbit chart](http://michelbaudin.com/2013/05/20/orbit-charts-and-why-you-should-use-them/)

I would ideally like to be able to create interactive versions (such as Plotly) but a ggplot2 would suffice as well.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a weekly vis contest some time ago, I created some charts like this.  I think the commonly accepted term now is "connected scatterplot".

Here is the skeleton `plotly` code I used.

```
plot_ly(
  df,
  x = x_var,
  y = y_var,
  group = group_var,
  mode = "markers") %>%
  add_trace(
    x = x_var,
    y = y_var,
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title = ""),
    group = group_var,
    line = list(shape = "spline"),
    showlegend = FALSE,
    hoverinfo = "none")
```

You can look at the [github repo for my submission](https://github.com/jkaupp/2016-14) which includes the code for both `ggplot` and `plotly` to produce connected scatterplots.

Answer (score 1):

Using ggplot2:

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they appear in the data. `geom_line()` connects them in order of the variable on the x axis.

Taken from the ggplot manual page: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_path.html

You may also try out `geom_curve` and `geom_segment` if you want more control.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bishop, I was able to formulate something really close to my ideal orbit chat. I included some chart annotations, for the start and end date and a label for which direction is the optimal solution.

```
max_date <- final_data_grp[which.max(final_data_grp$week_num), ]
min_date <- final_data_grp[which.min(final_data_grp$week_num), ]

end <- list(
  x = max_date$AreaWOH,
  y = max_date$SLevel,
  text = paste('End', max_date$MondayDate),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y"
)

start <- list(
  x = min_date$AreaWOH,
  y = min_date$SLevel,
  text = paste('Start', min_date$MondayDate),
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y"
)

best_label = list(
  x = min(final_data_grp$AreaWOH),
  y = max(final_data_grp$SLevel),
  text = 'Best Scenario',
  showarrow = FALSE,
  bordercolor='#c7c7c7',
  borderwidth=2,
  borderpad=4,
  bgcolor='#ff7f0e',
  opacity=.7
)

plot_ly(
  final_data_grp,
  x = AreaWOH,
  y = SLevel,
  group = MondayDate,
  showlegend = FALSE,
  marker = list(size = 8,
                color = 'black',
                opacity = .6)) %>% 
  add_trace(
    x = AreaWOH,
    y = SLevel,
    line = list(shape = "spline"),
    hoverinfo = "none",
    showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(annotations = list(start, end, best_label))
```